# Not able to set number of facets returned using Tire, correctly in console

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

So I have this straightforward query that I'm trying to run

```
Tire.search('posts', :size => 15) do
  query{ string '*'}
  facet('keywords'){ terms :keywords, :global => true }
end.results.facets['keywords']['terms'].each_with_index{|x, i| puts "#{i} - #{x.inspect}" }
```

but no matter what I do it keeps returning 10 results

this works correctly though

```
Tire.search('posts', :size => 15) do
  query{ string '*' }
  facet('keywords'){ terms :keywords }
end.results.each_with_index{|x, i| puts "#{x.title} - #{i}" } and false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the number of entries in the returned facets,
you need to set the size in the facet definition:

```
Tire.search('posts') do
  query{ string '*' }
  facet('keywords'){ terms :keywords, :size => 15 }
end.
  results.facets['keywords']['terms'].each_with_index{|x, i| puts "#{i} - #{x.inspect}"}
```

The `size` parameter for the `Tire.search` controls how many results you want to retrieve.